# C# Inconsistent accessibility: return type is less accessible than method

Tags: c#, .net, access-modifiers

Im working on a app for my study. now i just started a app where i got a database with the soccer league's and the clubs etc. now i had a list with the club and the players now im trying to add in more league's then just 1. but i get this error when im doing the same thing then doing before.
this is the code of the not working list:

```
public List<Competitie> GetAllCompetities()
        {
            List<Competitie> Competitie = new List<Competitie>();
            using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                string query = "Select * from competitie";
                MySqlCommand selectallcompetitiecommand = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
                MySqlDataReader reader = selectallcompetitiecommand.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Competitie comp = new Competitie();
                    comp.IdCompetitie = reader.GetInt32(0);
                    comp.NaamCompetitie = reader.GetString(1);
                    Competitie.Add(comp);
                }
            }
            return Competitie;
        }
```

and then this is the code of the clubs this do is working:

```
public List<Clubs> GetAllClubs(string selecteditem)
        { //Zorgt voor alle dingen van de tabel clubs.
            List<Clubs> Clubs = new List<Clubs>();
            using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {  
                connection.Open();
                string query = "Select * from databasevoetbal.clubs where competitie.naamcompetie = '" + selecteditem + "' and clubs.idcompetitie = competitie.idcompetitie";
                MySqlCommand selectAllClubsCommand = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
                MySqlDataReader reader = selectAllClubsCommand.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Clubs Club = new Clubs();
                    Club.idClubs = reader.GetInt32(0);
                    Club.NaamClubs = reader.GetString(1);
                    Club.aantalkampioenschappen = reader.GetInt32(2);
                    Club.opgericht = reader.GetInt32(3);
                    Club.idcompetitie = reader.GetInt32(4);
                    Clubs.Add(Club);
                }
            }
            return Clubs;
        }
```

It's the same code only the query in the club uses a selected item from a listbox but anybody knows why i get this error in the first list:

> Error CS0050  Inconsistent accessibility: return type
>   '`List<Competitie>`' is less accessible than method
>   '`DatabaseManager.GetAllCompetities()`'

Code for the class:

```
class Competitie
    {
        public int IdCompetitie { get; set; }
        public string NaamCompetitie { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0}", NaamCompetitie);
        }
    }
```

Comment: where did you define the `Competitie` class? And is it `public`, or not? If not, then that might explain the error, because then there's a chance that code which can call the GetAllCompetities() method (because it's `public`) cannot access the class which the method returns. And clearly that is not a logical situation

Comment: Dont forget to close any open connection. connection.Close();

Comment: with the using it automatic closes the connection

Comment: @SerhatOz I think you don't understand what `using` does.

Comment: yeah so it needs to be `public class Competitie`. Otherwise it defaults to being `internal` (i.e.accessible only within the assembly it's compiled into). As the error says, the class must be at least as accessible as the method which returns it

Comment: @adyson i updated the question with the class

Comment: @Jdiehl in your code/question you have the following class Competitie ....it must be: public class Competitie. If you don't give an access modifier, a class by default is internal. That's adyson is trying to tell you.

Comment: Unrelated tips: the MySqlCommand and MySqlDataReader are both IDisposable, so each should be in a `using` block. And beware the Sql injection vulnerability: use parameters rather than string concatenation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You must make your class public:

```
public class Competitie
```

If you don't specify the access modifier, it defaults to being `internal` (i.e.accessible only within the assembly it's compiled into).

As the error says, the class must be at least as accessible as the method which returns it.

The way you've got it now, there's a chance that code which can call the GetAllCompetities() method (because it's public) cannot access the class which the method returns. And clearly that is not a logical situation - the calling code would not be able use or understand the data it gets back.

N.B. Depending on the context, it might actually be more appropriate instead to mark the GetAllCompetities() method as `internal` to match the class. That way none of it is accessible outside the assembly. It's entirely dependent on your situation and what you need, though. I'm just noting that for completeness. It would resolve the error, but result in a different level of accessibility for these pieces of code.

Here is the documentation for C# access modifiers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/access-modifiers

Comment: Just being Devil's advocate, but note that it may be equally appropriate to fix this by changing the `GetAll...` method to be internal; it just depends what things you want to expose.

Comment: @Richardissimo that's a very good point actually. I'll update the answer, thankyou